# Pimcore how to detect save and publish

Tags: event-handling, pimcore-v5

Under Pimcore 5, i would like to do something(eg send an email) when user click « save & publish » . 
How can i **hook** this event ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that an event is triggered when save & publish is clicked. But when you save an document/object/asset the update lifecycle starts. So if you hook into preUpdate you could check for $e->getDocument()->isPublished() and you would get the actual state if it's published. Downside to this is, if it was already published and you would hit it again, it would trigger as well. You could, however, store a flag if you sent your email or whatever, and check for this flag upon saving. (I think that would be how i would do it)

Hope this helps.

Cheers Remo

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    AppBundle\EventListener\TestListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: pimcore.asset.preUpdate, method: onPreUpdate }
```

File: src/AppBundle/EventListener/TestListener

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Pimcore\Event\Model\ElementEventInterface;
use Pimcore\Event\Model\DataObjectEvent;
use Pimcore\Event\Model\AssetEvent;
use Pimcore\Event\Model\DocumentEvent;

class TestListener {

    public function onPreUpdate (ElementEventInterface $e) {

        if($e instanceof AssetEvent) {
            // do something with the asset
            $foo = $e->getAsset(); 
        } else if ($e instanceof DocumentEvent) {
            // do something with the document
            $foo = $e->getDocument(); 
        } else if ($e instanceof DataObjectEvent) {
            // do something with the object
            $foo = $e->getObject(); 
            $foo->setMyValue(microtime(true));
            // we don't have to call save here as we are in the pre-update event anyway ;-) 
        }
    }
}
```

You might check for $e->getAsset()->isPublished();

From: https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Event_API_and_Event_Manager.html